# Why can't I find AD security group using the AD User and Computers tool?

Tags: active-directory, group, ou

I created a security group in AD. Using the AD Users and Computers tool, I can see it when I browse for it at the OU path, but I cannot see it using the "Find" function. Why is that?

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yubq.png) when I browse for the group.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERbC7.png) when I do a "Find" for the group.